# Bash script: How to setup classes and apply colors to those classes.

Tags: bash, colors

I have a script where I am currently applying color formatting to each line of code that I want color on.

```
 ## Shell color variables

 red=`tput setaf 1`
 green=`tput setaf 2`
 yellow=`tput setaf 3`
 reset=`tput sgr0`
 bold=`tput bold`

 ## Questions = yellow
 ## Actions = green
 ## Errors = red


 read -p "${yellow}${bold}What is your name?${reset} " hostname
 echo "${green}Pulling up a list of files that begin with $FILELIST ...${reset}"
 echo "${red}File already exists! Exiting...${reset}"
```

This is not the complete script just a sample of what it looks like but for the most part its mainly applying colors to the script output using echos and what you see above. The problem is, for each line I have whether its a question, and action, or an error, I am defining that on each line. This is a very lengthy script and going line by line to apply formatting is very tedious work. There has got to be a better way. Is there a way to define classes and apply color to those classes so I do not have to specify it on each line? I'm thinking that since most of my colored lines use echo, just create some echo variables at the top like this:

```
##This is for a question:

echoq=$(echo -e "\033[1;93m"this is my question text in yellow"\033[m")

or 

echoq=$(${yelllow}${bold}"this is my question text in yellow"${reset})

##This is for an action

echoa=$(echo -e "\033[1;91m"this is my action text in red"\033[m")

or 

echoa=$(${red}${bold}"this is my action text in red"${reset})
```

Then once I have all of my variables defined, I just use echoq, echoa, or echor, where it applies. Is something like this viable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, with [functions](http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/08/what-you-need-to-know-about-bash-functions/) ---

```
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
reset=$(tput sgr0)

echoq() {
    echo "${yellow}$1${reset}"
        # $1 is the first parameter to echoq, not the first parameter to your script
}

echoq "This is a question"  # Prints in yellow
```

You can then copy `echoq` to `echoa` and `echor`, and just change `${yellow}` to `${red}` or whatever color or escape sequence you want.

**Edit**: In answer to your question, the string in `echoq` has three parts, all jammed together:

```
${yellow}            The value of the "yellow" variable --- change to yellow
         $1          The parameter to echoq.  You can also write this as ${1}.
           ${reset}  The value of the "reset" variable --- Reset the terminal
```

So `$1$` is actually `$1` plus the leading `$` of `${reset}`.  You would still use `$1` in each function, since each function gets its own parameters just like each script does.

Comment: What does the $1$ do in the middle? Would I use $1$ in all my functions or would I need to increment that number by one each function?

Comment: @user53029 Edited to explain.

Comment: This is a correct answer. +1. But I would recommend using `"$@"` instead of `"$1"`, because then you can use `echo`-like  syntax: `echoq This is a question`

Comment: @anishsane Good point; that works fine.  I actually chose `$1` on purpose to avoid surprises for the OP.  Imagine `echop What is your name?` (no `""`) run in a directory containing a file called `names`.  The result will be `What is your names` because of pathname expansion (I just tested this ;) ).  Since the OP is comfortable with `echo ""`, I figured it was better to stick with that and avoid the chance of confusion due to unexpected expansion.

Comment: ^^ Hmm... fair point. Also, I would have written function like: `printf "%s" "$yellow"; echo "$@"; printf "%s" "$reset"`, so that all the options to `echor` will be passed as-is to `echo`...

Comment: @anishsane Good idea - add it as an answer and I'll upvote it :) .  Why `printf "%s" "$yellow"` and not just `printf "$yellow$"`?  Is it in case `$yellow` includes a `%`?

Comment: ^^ yes, that's the general reason. For this case, it would work. but I don't want to encourage OP to use something like `printf "$yellow"`